# Scikit learn in QGIS does not work (Windows 10)

Tags: qgis, python, import, windows-10, scikit-learn

I tried to install scikit-learn in OSGeo4W Shell.

I used the information provided by another question [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281434/installing-scikit-learn-python-package-for-qgis-on-win).
Both ways as AlecZ suggested worked.

After installation I get this message: "Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.24.2"

Although when I open QGIS and then try to import sklearn I get this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils'"

How can I fix that and import the library?

Comment: which Operating System are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, you must activate the QGIS environment before using pip

For QGIS 3.20 and higher: Open OsGeo shell, then type:

`o4w_env`

`python3 -m pip install scikit-learn -U --user`

For QGIS 3.18 and lower: Open OsGeo shell, then type:

`py3_env.bat`

`python3 -m pip install scikit-learn -U --user`

Comment: I have QGIS 3.18 and I already did those steps but still, the same error pops up

Comment: can you please add the successful installation message to your question? It might give some clues about what went wrong. Namely, the path where the scikit package was installed.

Comment: I uninstalled 3.18 and install 3.20 and all worked well!